# Find triple integral over a tetrahedron constructed by 3 planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is as follows:

> Find triple integral of **f(x,y,z) = xy + z by dxdydz**
>
> Over the tetrahedron D  created by the following coordinates: $(0,0,0),
> (1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$

My answer doesn't agree with the book's answer.  I got $\frac{3}{20}$ while the books gives $\frac{1}{20}$.  I suspect that my integrands for $dxdy$ are incorrect somehow, but I still don't quite see what I did wrong >_<

**My work:**

**(1)** The region $D$ looks like the following picture
[image]

**(2)** So my thoughts are the following:

**a.** To work with $dx$, I consider the $xy$ plane (or $yx$ plane).  I note that $y = 0$ when $x = 1$ and $y =1$ when $x = 0$.  So the upper bound is the line $y = - x + 1$, or $x = 1 - y$.  The lower bound is $x = 0$.  So $x$ goes from $0$ to $1-y$.

**b.** With $dy$, I consider the $yz$ plane (or $zy$ plane).  Since $z = 0$ when $y = 1$ and $z=1$ when $y = 0$, the equation for upper bound of $y$ is $z = -y + 1$, or $y = 1- z$.  So $y$ goes from $0$ to $1-z$

**c.** With $dz$, lower bound is $0$ and upper bound is $1$

So the triple integral becomes
$$ \int_0^1   \int_0^{1-z}   \int_0^{1-y}  (xy + z) dxdydz$$

And after some lengthy works, I got $\frac{3}{20}$
But the book's answer is $\frac{1}{20}$.  So is my work wrong anywhere?
I strongly suspect that to work with $dx$, I should consider the $xz$ plane instead of $xy$ plane (I'm trying the "shooting arrow" method through the region)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your first integral be $\int_0^{1-y-z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane containing $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ is $x+y+z=1$. Therefore, your interval for the x-axis is $x=0$ to $x=1-y-z$, for the y-axis it's $y=0$ to $y=1$, and for the z-axis it's $z=0$ to $z=1$.

Therefore your integral should be:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z}\int_{0}^{1-y-z}(xy+z)\space{dx}\space{dy}\space{dz}$$

Comment: That still doesn't look right, the bounds for z and y can't both be 0 to 1 otherwise it would be a rectangle

Comment: For that order of integration you would need $0 < x < 1-y-z $, $0 <y <1-z$, $0 < z < 1 $.