# Finding the boundaries on a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Solve:
$$\iiint yz \,dV$$
Over the tetrahedron with vertices on the points $$A(0,0,0), B(1,1,0), C(1,0,0), D(1,0,1)$$ 
Well, I proceeded to find a the equation of a plane which contained B, C and D. 
If I did it correctly which I think I did, the plane equation is x=1.
My problem arises when choosing the limits. I can't find a relation between x, y and z.So by looking at the graph I concluded that the upper limits would all be 1.
$$\int^1_0\int^1_0\int^1_0yz \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
Was I correct to make this assumption? Otherwise, where did I make a mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying that the set of inequalities $$\begin{cases} 0\le x\le 1 \\ 0\le y\le 1 \\ 0\le z\le 1\end{cases}$$ describes a tetrahedron?

Comment: I guess not. I could express z in of y since the projection on the plane xz is represented by y=z. Does that help somehow?

Comment: Hint: Upon drawing this, I find that the "interesting" face of this tetrahedron is contained in the plane with points $A$, $B$, and $D$. The equation of that plane is $-x+y+z=0$ (how did I figure that out?). So then we can say that $z$ takes all values between $0\le z\le x-y$ (that is, all the values from the $xy$-plane up to the interesting plane). Then you consider the projection of the tetrahedron onto the $xy$-plane (because now we want a relationship between $x$ and $y$) to get some bounds on either $x$ in terms of y or $y$ in terms of $x$. Then the last will of course be $0\le\ ? \le 1$.

Comment: And thus you have the three inequalities describing this region.

Comment: The proyection on the xy plane is the line x=1, so y doesn't depend on x at all. Same with the xz plane, on the yz plane though, I find that $y=z$.

Comment: On the $xy$-plane you should see $y=x$ is one of the boundaries.  [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/AiNXlbQ.png) an image of what the tetrahedron should look like.  Imagine the sun is directly over the tetrahedron.  Then the shadow it makes on the $xy$-plane is its projection on the $xy$-plane.  You should see that it is a region bounded by $y=0$, $x=1$ and $y=x$.  Two of those equations can be used to give an inequality of one variable in terms of the other.

Comment: Very similar questions have been posed and solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/404275) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/457484).

Answer (score 1):

The relations between $x$, $y$ and $z$ can be found from the equations of the planes that contain the faces of the tetrahedron.
The plane that contains the vertices $AND$ contains yje vectors $\vec B=(1,1,0)^T$ and $\vec D=(1,0,1)^T$ so it is orthogonal to the vector $\vec A \times \vec B=(1,-1,-1)^T$ and its equation is:
$$
x-y-z=0
$$
since the minimum value of $z$ is $z=0$, this gives the limits for z:
$$
0<z<x-y
$$
the intersection of this plane vith the $xy$ plane ($z=0$) is the line $x-y=0$
that gives the limits for $y$: $0<y<x$, and the limits for $x$ are obviously $0<x<1$.

So the integral becomes:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^{x-y} yz\;dzdydx
$$